# python S60 Application access

Tags: python, nokia, s60

I wrote simple application for my Symbian mobile(Nokia 5800). Let's say it something like this:

```
import appuifw 
appuifw.app.screen = "normal"
appuifw.app.title = u'Group 13'
colors = [u"red", u"green", u"blue", u"brown"]
index = appuifw.selection_list(colors, 1) 
if index == 2: 
   print "blue is correct!" 
elif index != None:
   print "Bzz! " + colors[index] + " is not correct"
```

Then I convert it with "Python for S60"(ensymble) to make .sis file.

But when I install it, it asks me to allow application to use connectivity application, read user data, write user data, use camera and etc(Application access).

Is there any way to get rid of all of that functions, or not letting it access it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution!

In ensymble there are Additional options which includes capabilities.

*By default, the sis files are generated with the following capabilities: LocalServices, NetworkServices, ReadUserData, WriteUserData, UserEnvironment*

*If a different set of capabilities is needed for the application, then it can be specified using the --caps option.*

*--caps=Cap1+Cap2+...*

*-b Cap1+Cap2+...*

So when you create .sis file you can chose which capabilities to include

Addition information can be found here: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Capabilities